# How to call `property_exists()` on a class property from within said class?

Tags: php

If I create the instance of the class like so

```
$template = new EmailTemplate(array('templateFile' =>'template__test.php'));
```

Why does the following echo `NULL`?

```
class EmailTemplate {
    private $templateFile;

    function __construct($args) {
        foreach($args as $key => $val) {
            if(property_exists($this, $this->{$key})) {
                $this->{$key} = $val;
            }
            echo $this->templateFile;
        }
}
```

I was expecting the constructor to echo "template__test.php".

Any help?

Comment: `if(property_exists($this, $key)) { ... }`

Comment: Damnit. Spent way to long looking at that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a little on why it works that way? Seems strange that `$this->{$key}` sets the value, but just `$key` is enough to see if it exists.

Comment: @crowhill at the time when the control is in the property_exists(), the value of $this->{$key} has yet to be set but the value for $key is set. The part that actually sets the value of $this->{$key} comes AFTER calling the property_exists() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the constructor like this:

```
    class EmailTemplate {

        private $templateFile;        

        function __construct( $args ) {

            // Loop through the arguments
            foreach ( $args as $key => $val ) {

                // Check if the current class has a defined variable 
                // named as the value of $val
                if ( property_exists( $this, $key ) ) {

                    // If it has, set it to the passed value
                    $this->$key = $val;

                   // If you pass multiple array items, you should echo $this->$key;
                }

                // Print the defined variable to screen
                echo $this->templateFile;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above is correct. But the only real difference is using `propery_exists($this, $key)` instead of `property_exists($this, $this->{$key})`